# YouTube public video embed shows "This video isn't available"

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist, embed

I have a [public video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHOX6jH00kE) that I embedded on [my website](https://brokkolat.org/en/cancao/1) with this code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UHOX6jH00kE?autoplay=1&loop=1&list=UHOX6jH00kE" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen)
```

This embed shows an error:

[image: YouTube embed error]

even though the video is public and made for kids.

How can I fix it?

Comment: The question doesn't include enough context to see this as a problem about using web applications instead of handling a website / programming besides, troubleshooting questions are off.-topic here. It might be more appropriate for [webmasters.se] or for [so]

Comment: Yes, indeed. I asked about it here and it's a bug on YouTube that I reported on the Issue Tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right GET parameter is `playlist`, not `list. So this is the working link:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/UHOX6jH00kE?autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=UHOX6jH00kE
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041088/getting-an-embedded-youtube-video-to-auto-play-and-loop